# amazon ads for swift not working in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i am trying to implement the amazon ads for ios using swift.The code provided by amazon is in Objective C and i have tried mirroring it to the swift but failed to do so.The following methods "**adViewDidLoad**" and "**adViewDidFailToLoad**" which were working in Objective C  have stopped working in swift,but the function "**viewControllerForPresentingModalView**" is working across both languages.Here is  snippet of my code

@IBOutlet weak var amazonAdView: AmazonAdView!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    var option1 = AmazonAdOptions()
    option1.isTestRequest = false
    amazonAdView.delegate = self

    self.amazonAdView.loadAd(option1)

}

func viewControllerForPresentingModalView() -> UIViewController {
    println("........here.......")
return self;
}


 func adViewDidLoad(View : AmazonAdView) {
     println("........here.1......")
NSLog("Successfully loaded an ad");
}


// @optional
func adViewDidFailToLoad(View :AmazonAdView , withError: AmazonAdError ) {
NSLog("Ad Failed to load. Error code ")
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been having similar struggles and am confused as to whether its Amazon, or me. I implemented it as follows and the ad appears sometimes, I'm not sure what causes it to not appear at times, and it does not trip the delegate functions like it should when it fails. I had it working with this setup for several days, and as soon as I flipped the flag to production, it never showed up again. So I'm not sure if that has something to do with it.

```
func setupAmazonAd(){
    if(testAmazonAd != nil){
        testAmazonAd?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    testAmazonAd = AmazonAdView(adSize: AmazonAdSize_320x50)

    var adOptions = AmazonAdOptions()
    // During development, you must tell the framework that the
    // app is not a production version
    adOptions.isTestRequest = true
    testAmazonAd!.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.testAmazonAd!)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.testAmazonAd!)
}

func viewControllerForPresentingModalView() -> UIViewController! {
    return self
}

func adViewWillExpand(view: AmazonAdView!) {
    println("Will present modal view for an ad. Its time to pause other activities.")
}

func adViewDidCollapse(view: AmazonAdView!) {
    println("Modal view has been dismissed, its time to resume the paused activities.")
}

func adViewDidLoad(view: AmazonAdView!) {
    println("Successfully loaded an ad")
}

func adViewDidFailToLoad(view: AmazonAdView, error:AmazonAdError){
    println("Failed to Load")
}
```